# JQuery scroller broken by Chrome v61's new scrolling conformance! :(

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that has been behaving awesomely... until I looked at it today and it won't scroll, and the menu won't work.

Here is the URL...

[Thunderbox Entertainment](http://thunderboxentertainment.com/)

I am looking at it in Chrome, and I can't scroll down with my mouse wheel, and the menu items do nothing when I click on them. I haven't touched it, and it was working fine last week.

If I move my mouse to the far right, a vertical scroll bar appears and I can use that to scroll...

It also seems to work fine in Chrome on my iPad.

A bit of research tells me that this is caused by Chrome v61 updating the way it handles scrolling.

The code could be broken in multiple places, but here is an example that I suspect no longer works...

```js
// Quick scrolling to content
  // ...................................................................
  $fullSlider.data('scrolling', false);
  var autoScrollTime = 650, 
   scrollEasing = 'easeInOutQuart', 
   pos = false;

  // DOMMouseScroll = Mozilla, onmousewheel = IE, mousewheel = everything else
  $('body').on('mousewheel onmousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
   e = e.originalEvent || window.event;                        // Get the event
   wheelData = e.detail ? -e.detail : e.wheelDelta / 40;       // Wheel data for different browsers   
   contentStart = $('#AfterSlider').offset().top - wpAdminbar; // beginning of page content
   pos = Math.round(contentStart - $(document).scrollTop());   // Distance from top padder
   screenWidth =  $(window).width(); // Only use on large screens

   if ($fullSlider.data('scrolling')) {
    return false; // disable wheel
   } else {
    if (screenWidth < 768 || window.mobilecheck())
     return true; // do nothing on small screens
    if (wheelData < 0 ) {
     //scroll down
     scrollDir = 'down';
     // Auto scroll to content
     if ( pos > 20 ) {
      $fullSlider.data('scrolling', 'down'); // mark as active
      // Scroll to position
      $.scrollTo( contentStart, autoScrollTime, { 
       easing: scrollEasing, 
       onAfter: function() { $fullSlider.data('scrolling', false); } // mark complete
      });
      return false; // disable wheel (smoother effect)
     }
    } else {
     //scroll up
     scrollDelta = (scrollDir != 'up') ? 0 : scrollDelta; // reset delta on direction change
     scrollDir = 'up';
     // Auto scroll to slideshow
     if ( pos >= -1 ) {
      $fullSlider.data('scrolling', 'up'); // mark as active
      // Scroll to position
      $.scrollTo( 0, autoScrollTime, {
       easing: scrollEasing, 
       onAfter: function() { $fullSlider.data('scrolling', false); } // mark complete
      });
      return false; // disable wheel (smoother effect)
     } 
     // Hard stop at content top
     scrollDelta = (scrollDelta < 620) ? scrollDelta + (wheelData * 45) : scrollDelta; // should be (wheelData * 40) but we're being conservative
     scrollEndPos = pos + scrollDelta;
     if ( pos < -1 && (pos > -120 || scrollEndPos > -160) ) {
      $fullSlider.data('scrolling', 'top'); // mark as active
      jQuery.scrollTo.window().stop(true);
      // Scroll to position
      $.scrollTo( contentStart, 455, {
       easing: 'easeOutBack', 
       onAfter: function() { 
        $.scrollTo( contentStart, 1); // make sure it hit the target
        setTimeout( function() { $fullSlider.data('scrolling', false); }, 135); // mark complete
       }
      });
      return false;
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

Thanks for your help!
Dan

Comment: For some insight as to why this is getting such a low score, see [this page on what topics are appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [this page on how to format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "My website is broken" doesn't help anybody.

Comment: Did you inspect the site and look at the console errors?  You will see that go_pricing_styles.css is not getting loaded

Comment: Ah... There is a highly suspect console error. Nice catch. Not sure why this is no longer working though. Let me investigate! Thanks, sn3ll!

Comment: Drat. Fixed all that stuff and the problem still persists.

Comment: OK. According to the support forums, other users of this WordPress theme have starting having the same mysterious issue. I will let you know if any resolution is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

"The custom scrolling (scrollbars) is an optional setting. If you think it might cause problems on your site you can turn it off from the admin settings and return to the browser’s default scrolling. As far as we know (and from the thousands of installs of the theme) there is no problem with the custom scrolling in Chrome. If there were, you could always disable it."

I read this comments in support section of theme you are using.
Hope that it will help you.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks!
I tried this, based on your suggestion, but the issue still persists.
:(